# Submitting hidden as well as non hidden form field angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to submit a form which is having both hidden and non hidden form field.

My component HTML look like:

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="addMyForm(myForm.value);">
            <section class="form-block">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="endPointType" [(ngModel)]="endPointType" [value]="WAVEFRONT" [hidden]="true" required>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Endpoint Name</label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Endpoint Name" name="name" [(ngModel)]="name" required>
                </div>
            </section>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button>
        </form>
```

While submitting this form the POST body I am getting in component class as `{"name":"bla bla"}` but I want POST body data as `{"name":"bla bla", "endPointType":"something"}` What is the issue in my code?

Comment: @AmitChigadani May I know the reason of using `*ngIf`?

Comment: Seems working here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hoq6rn-rc7aox?file=src/app/keyup.components.ts

Comment: I don't know if it depends on the browser or the way form is submitted, but tests i made with requests totally ignored parameters that had the value `undefined`. So you can log it, as @PardeepJain example shows but maybe it's not transmitted to the request. Maybe you can try with a default value such an empty string `''` or `false`

Comment: Yes @Kaddath because once you pass the value as `JSON.stringify` into the post method Javascript will ignore all the key-value pair whose value is undefined.

Comment: _"What is the issue in my code?"_ Hard to say without seeing your code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the default value for `endPointType` in your controller in order to avoid this problem.

**Reason** : [**working example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hoq6rn-rc7aox?file=src%2Fapp%2Fkeyup.components.ts)

The reason behind this if you send value as it is you get from submitting method it contained `endPointType` value as `undefined`. which logged perfactly as shown in the example.

```
{endPointType: undefined, name: "fsdfsd"}
```

But When you send data to the server you are sending data by parsing it to Stringify. which removed all the keys whose value is `undefined`
so the result will be -

```
"{name: 'fsdfsd'}"
```

## Update

To set default value just initialize your variable like this -

```
export class yourClassName {
...
endPointType = 'WAVEFRONT'
...
}
```

and use while sending data to server-

```
{endPointType: this.endPointType, name: "fsdfsd"}
```

Comment: I just want the value submitted by form as: {endPointType: "WAVEFRONT", name: "fsdfsd"}

Comment: This will be achieved , you need to set default value of `endPointType` as `WAVEFRONT`

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: check my Updated answer

Comment: That is not the solution I want. Do we have any way to initialize this in HTML itself?

Comment: Then you must set their value on click in the method